# NSVIew not showing until resize window

Tags: cocoa, nsview, layer

I'm using Storyboard and auto layout to create a cocoa program.
[Storyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCN8w.png)

One weird symptom I'm experiencing: the localVideo NSView doesn't show up when the program initially runs. It's only until I resize the window, the localVideo NSView immediately shows up:
[Window Resize NSView Appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJiUZ.gif)

I'm not setting any constraints in code, it's all done in autolayout. The only thing I do in code is set the background color of the views:

```
self.view.wantsLayer = YES;
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.remoteVideo.wantsLayer = YES;
self.remoteVideo.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor].CGColor;
self.localVideo.wantsLayer = YES;
self.localVideo.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

Any clue as to what is going on here?

Note - there are some cases where the NSView shows up at run. It's not always reproducible and I can't determine what's causing it to or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Where does this code live? ``viewDidLoad``?, ``viewWillAppear``?, ``awakeFromNib``?, or somewhere else?

Comment: It's sitting in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Try moving the code that sets the ``backgroundColor`` properties to ``viewWillAppear``, but leave all the ``wantsLayer`` lines where they are.

Comment: That did, it thank you so much!!! How do I reward you for a comment? And the all important question - why?

Comment: False alarm - it still seems sporadic. Worked for a bit, then back to the old behavior.

Comment: Log the layer at the point at which you're setting its background color, does it exist, or is it nil?

Comment: The NSView is showing up again, so log says view does exist. When it does, it seems like it will for a period of time, until I do something (not sure what - sleep/wake laptop, plug in external monitor, etc.). Then it will consistently not work...

Comment: 2016-08-12 19:19:58.379 Agora Mac Tutorial Objective-C[6886:1752089] Layer exists!
2016-08-12 19:19:58.379 Agora Mac Tutorial Objective-C[6886:1752089] RemoteVideo layer exists!
2016-08-12 19:19:58.379 Agora Mac Tutorial Objective-C[6886:1752089] LocalVideo layer exists!

Comment: `if (self.view.layer)`
`NSLog(@"Layer exists!");`
`if (self.remoteVideo.layer)`
`NSLog(@"RemoteVideo layer exists!");`
`if (self.localVideo.layer)`
`NSLog(@"LocalVideo layer exists!");`